# How to ping different devices at different time intervals efficiently

Tags: c#, .net, design-patterns, timer

I am trying to create an application that pings the devices configured by the user and reflects the status online or offline. A user can specify IP and Ping Interval for a device and based on that configuration the application needs to ping the device. For example, if the user specifies IP 198.67.227.143 and Ping Interval as 5 seconds, then the application will ping 198.67.227.143 every 5 seconds and reflect the status of whether the device is online or offline.

There can be multiple devices with different ping intervals configured. For example, Device A has a ping interval of 10 seconds and Device B has a ping interval of 20 seconds.

I want to know what is the best way to check whether a device should be pinged or not. Currently, the solution I can come up with is setting up a process that runs every second and loops through all the configured devices and checks if the device should be pinged or not based on the LastPingTime of the device.

Is there a better way of approaching this problem? I am trying to accomplish this in C# and .NET 4.6.2.

Comment: I would have tried the other way out, instead of making an application or service ping devices how about the device itself mark itself as online for every 5 seconds. If the device did not mark itself in that time you can consider it as offline. Later you can have a background app which will monitor this device online data from the db where the device online data is stored

Comment: @SandeepPandey nice idea. But I want the application to be generic and anyone can use it to ping devices without making changes to their actual device. The idea of the application is to allow users to check the status of all of his/her devices in a configurable way. That is the user can configure what will be the ping interval. Your idea cannot accommodate the requirement of configurable ping intervals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option you can try to have different timers for reach devices, you don't need to ping every second for each device.

I have done simple basic implantation for this, you can use this concept in your code.

```
//each device representation
public class Device
{
    public string IpAddress { get; set; }
    public int PingInterval { get; set; }
    public Timer PingTimer { get; set; }
    public bool IsOnline { get; set; }
}

public class DeviceManager
{
    private List<Device> _devices;

    public DeviceManager()
    {
        _devices = new List<Device>();
    }

    public void AddDevice(string ipAddress, int pingInterval)
    {
        var device = new Device
        {
            IpAddress = ipAddress,
            PingInterval = pingInterval
        };

        device.PingTimer = new Timer(OnPingTimerElapsed, device, TimeSpan.Zero, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(pingInterval));

        _devices.Add(device);
    }

    private void OnPingTimerElapsed(object state)
    {
        //you can log the device state at this place
        var device = (Device)state;

        // ping and update the status of the device
        device.IsOnline = SendPing(device.IpAddress);
    }

    private bool SendPing(string ipAddress)
    {
        //ping logic implementation;
    }
}
```

you can call like this.

```
DeviceManager deviceManager = new DeviceManager();
deviceManager.AddDevice("10.220.63.36", 5);
deviceManager.AddDevice("10.220.63.37", 10);
```

Comment: I implemented this solution and it works fine. But I have concerns about the scalability of this approach. As far as I know, Timer runs in a separate thread. This means I occupy a different thread for any new device I add. So, as the number of devices increase the number of threads occupied increases. Although not all thread will be active at a time but there can be cases where the timers overlap for several devices and hence there can be multiple threads active at a time. In worst case can it cause Thread Pool Starvation? Should I be concerned about this?

Comment: @HemBhagat yes, you are right. you can have a single timer with different intervals as well. just refer to this https://stackoverflow.com/a/4468750/6527049

Comment: I had a look. But it won't be a good solution as it ticks every second. It will be similar to what I first come up with. Also, the ping interval will be variable in my case, so ticking the time every second and then identifying which all devices should be pinged will not be a good idea.

Comment: @HemBhagat just explore around async await